# deserialize JSON with no default constructor

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm migrating an existing communication layer to use REST with JSON. The previous framework did not require a default constructor of the transferring POJOs.

I can not make changes on the model classes being transferred, so annotations are not an option. Also Mixins are not an option as well. 
It should be a central configuration.

This is the current configuration & test code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false);

PrivateObject object = new PrivateObject(1234, "test");
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
PrivateObject result = mapper.readValue(jsonString, PrivateObject.class);
```

POJO example:

```
public class PrivateObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public PrivateObject(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

JSON example:

```
{"id":1234,"name":"test"}
```

Resulting exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.softmodeler.common.pojo.PrivateObject` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":1234,"name":"test"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without annotations or mixins if you use Java 8 or later:

- compile passing `-parameters` argument to javac
- include module `jackson-module-parameter-names` in your dependencies and register it e.g.
  `mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());`

more details [here](https://manosnikolaidis.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/jackson-without-annotations/)

Comment: I didn't have to add '-parameters' to the compiler arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: using the `ParanamerModule` instead of the `ParameterNamesModule`, does not require to change the compiler arguments.

**[ParanamerModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/paranamer)**:

Module that uses Paranamer library to auto-detect names of Creator

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParanamerModule());
```

**[ParameterNamesModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names)**:

Jackson module that adds support for accessing parameter names; a feature added in JDK 8.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
```

**Preconditions**:

class Person must be compiled with Java 8 compliant compiler with option to store formal parameter names turned on (**-parameters option**). For more information about Java 8 API for accessing parameter names at runtime see this